# Remover "margem" de imagem responsiva em site por CSS

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

Boa tarde! Sou iniciante em programação voltado a web, e estou com dificuldades em remover um espaço que chamo de "margem" da imagem de fundo da pagina, que esta responsivo com uma `width:100%` (**imaginava que com isto ele deveria ocupar toda a largura da pagina, mas não esta ocupando totalmente, esta apresentando uma pequena "margem"**) eu queria que ela estivesse sem esta "margem" ou seja, encostando totalmente no canto da janela, podem me dar sujestoes do que esse problema se trata?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
html, body{
   margin:0px !important;
   padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tentastes na sua folha de estilo :

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

Esta é uma forma utilizada nos `resets`, e significa que tudo terá `margin:0`, e então você precisará declarar explicitamente os elementos que conterão margens.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
 div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Margem Misteriosa</h2>

<div>Existe elementos como a div, que por padrão tem uma margem que não sei da onde vem. Porque mesmo definindo 0px para a margin, ainda existe lá a maldita margin.<br></br>
Pra resolver isso basta definir o valor da margem para negativo.<br></br> Exemplo:<br></br>
div {<br></br>
margin-right: -8px;
margin-left: -8px;
<br></br>
}
</body>
</html>
```