# Como tirar as margens laterais dá pagina? HTML/CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Sou novo no ramo. Estou tentando montar um front para minha empresa atual. Eles pediram um protótipo.
Criei uma tela de login, porém a página fica com umas bordas padrão que não consigo tirar.
Eu quero que todo o conteúdo pegue toda a tela, sem borda nenhuma.
Como podem ver na imagem, tem bordas no topo, dos lados e em baixo.. quero sem nada, quero que pegue toda a pagina.[image: imagem para entender]
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Perdão se tiver erros de código e por favor me digam, assim me ajudaria nesse processo!=D

```css
.content{
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Faz com que não exceda o tamanho configurado no width/height*/
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, fantasy, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: static;

}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: static;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Faz com que não exceda o tamanho configurado no width/height*/
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden; /* faz o div não aumentar a altura por conta da imagem*/
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#f2f6f8+0,e0eff9+60,e0eff9+60,d8e1e7+88 */
background: rgb(242,246,248); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,246,248,1) 0%, rgba(224,239,249,1) 60%, rgba(224,239,249,1) 60%, rgba(216,225,231,1) 88%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,246,248,1) 0%,rgba(224,239,249,1) 60%,rgba(224,239,249,1) 60%,rgba(216,225,231,1) 88%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,246,248,1) 0%,rgba(224,239,249,1) 60%,rgba(224,239,249,1) 60%,rgba(216,225,231,1) 88%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f6f8', endColorstr='#d8e1e7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}
.logo{
    text-align: center;
}
.msg-login{
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Faz com que não exceda o tamanho configurado no width/height*/
}
h1#msg-login{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -8px;
    line-height: 5; /* espaçamento entre linhas */
}
section{
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    padding-bottom: 230px;
    border-block-start: 0px;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#f2f6f8+0,e0eff9+12,b5c6d0+60,d8e1e7+88 */
background: rgb(242,246,248); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,246,248,1) 0%, rgba(224,239,249,1) 12%, rgba(181,198,208,1) 60%, rgba(216,225,231,1) 88%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,246,248,1) 0%,rgba(224,239,249,1) 12%,rgba(181,198,208,1) 60%,rgba(216,225,231,1) 88%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,246,248,1) 0%,rgba(224,239,249,1) 12%,rgba(181,198,208,1) 60%,rgba(216,225,231,1) 88%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f6f8', endColorstr='#d8e1e7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}
#input-usuario{
    width: 350px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font: normal 15px sans-serif;
    color: #1d1c1ca8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #0ab3f7;
    outline: none; /* cor da borda quando você clica no input*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
#input-senha{
    width: 350px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font: normal 15px sans-serif;
    color: #1d1c1ca8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #0ab3f7;
    outline: none; /* cor da borda quando você clica no input*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
p.user-msg{
    line-height: 0; /* espaçamento entre linhas */
    padding-right: 300px;
}
p.password-msg{
    line-height: 0; /* espaçamento entre linhas */
    padding-right: 310px;
}
#idioma-msg {
    line-height: 4; /* espaçamento entre linhas */
    
}
#idioma {
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #0ab3f7;
    outline: none; /* cor da borda quando você clica no input*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(26, 128, 0);
}
a:hover{
    color: orangered;
}
button{
    padding-left: 15px 15px;
    font: normal 20px sans-serif;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #feffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #feffff 0%, #ddf1f9 48%, #a0d8ef 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 48%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #feffff 0%,#ddf1f9 48%,#a0d8ef 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffff', endColorstr='#a0d8ef',GradientType=0 );
    color: #034963;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #9c9c9c;
    /* text-indent: 5px; */
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    transform: translate(1px, 50px);
}
button:hover{ /*ao passar o mouse no botão, ele inverte o gradiente*/
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#a0d8ef+0,ddf1f9+52,feffff+100 */
background: #a0d8ef; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a0d8ef 0%, #ddf1f9 52%, #feffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a0d8ef 0%,#ddf1f9 52%,#feffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #a0d8ef 0%,#ddf1f9 52%,#feffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a0d8ef', endColorstr='#feffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
cursor: pointer; /*aparece uma mãozinha quando passa em cima.*/
}
#magentafooter{
    padding-top: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.far fa-user{
    padding-left: 15px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt'>
<head>
    <title>GTM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
            <header>
                <img src="logoedit.png" id="logo" width="300" height="100">
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="msg-login">
            <h1 id="msg-login">Entrar</h1>
        </div>
        <section>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                
                <label for="input-usuario"><p class="user-msg"></p><br></label>
                <i class="fa fa-group" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="text" id="input-usuario" value="" placeholder="Usuário" required="true">
                
                <label for="input-senha"><p class="password-msg"></p></label>
                <i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="password" id="input-senha" value="" placeholder="Senha" required="true">
            </form>
            <label for="idioma" id="idioma-msg">Idioma</label>
                <select name="idioma" id="idioma" required>
                    <option disabled selected>Selecione</option>
                    <option value="pt">Português</option>
                    <option value="en">Inglês</option>
                    <option value="es">Espanhol</option>
                </select><br>
            <div id="forget-pass" class="fp">
                
            </div>
            <a href="Mudar Senha/index-mudarSenha.html">Esqueceu sua senha?</a><br>
            <button type="submit"  id="button" onclick="(login())">Acessar</button>
        </section>
        <footer class="footer">
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Os navegadores podem tratar os elementos HTML em diferentes modos, e alguns elementos já vem com um estilo pré-definido, como html, body,p .... Basta abrir o inspector de elementos que você pode ver esses atributos com F12

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Remover "margem" de imagem responsiva em site por CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157333/remover-margem-de-imagem-responsiva-em-site-por-css)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize em seu CSS o seguinte trecho:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo... Valeu man